# export missing data from an R dataframe by creating a sheet for each subject in excel

Tags: r, excel

I would like to export in an excel file, the columns for which there are missing data by making a sheet for each subject.

For example, I have a data frame like this one:

| ID | Sexe | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 2 | 2 | 28 |
| 3 | NA | 32 |

For subject 1, we would have something like this in the 1st excel sheet:

| ID | Sexe | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |

And for subject 3 this :

| ID | Sexe | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | NA | 32 |

So there would be no sheet for subject 2 because no data is missing.

Do you think this is possible?

Here's the code to generate the df:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 3)
sexe <- c(1, 2, NA)
age <- c(NA,28,32)

df <- data.frame(ID, sexe, age)
```

In reality I have a much larger dataframe so I would have liked something automated

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Read about `complete.cases`

Comment: Yes, thank for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```r
# required package
library(openxlsx)

# define a function 
df_to_xlsx <- function(df, split_variable) {
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(df))
  
  df <- df[!complete.cases(df), ] 
  ls <- split(df, f = split_variable)
  ls <- ls[sapply(ls, nrow) > 0L]
  names(ls) <- paste0("Subject_", names(ls))
  # please specify your path, e.g. getwd() + file name.xlsx
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(ls, file = "mydata.xlsx", 
                       keepNA = TRUE, na.string = "NA") 
}

# use function 
df_to_xlsx(df = df, split_variable = ID)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This issues a warning

> #> Warning in split.default(x = seq_len(nrow(x)), f = f, drop = drop, ...): data
> #> length is not a multiple of split variable

due to the fact that the amount of ID levels (3) is unequal to the length of the list created by `split()` (2). This is because we subsetted by complete cases first, which removes the record of `ID == 2`, since it does not contain any `NA`s.

A piped approach:

```
df[!complete.cases(df), ] |>
  split(f = ID) |>
  { \(x) x[sapply(x, nrow) > 0L]}() |> 
  { \(x) setNames(object = x, nm = paste0("Subject_", names(x)))}() |>
  openxlsx::write.xlsx(x = _, file = "mydata.xlsx", 
                       keepNA = TRUE, na.string = "NA")
```